# Excel rounds the number when transferring from pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Creating a dataframe of float. Here's what pandas outputs:

```
   print(hh.iloc[2][Number])
   >>1028112000000713.0
```

And that 's what excel outputs:

```
1028112000000710
```

Output code to excel:

```
    xl = pd.ExcelWriter('gg.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(
            xl,
            sheet_name='ww',
            index=False)
```

I tried that:

```
    wb = xl.book
    ws = xl.sheets['ww']

    form = wb.add_format()
    form.set_num_format('################')
    ws.set_column('D:D', 18, form)
```

But it didn't work

Why does excel round numbers? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think Excel can't store more than 15 significant positions. See this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/).

> The number of digits of precision also limits the accuracy of the numbers. Excel store 15 significant digits of precision. For example, the number 1234567890123456 cannot be exactly represented if 15 digits of precision are used.

Your number has 16 positions.

This happens always in Excel. It is not an issue with Pandas or Python writing the value to Excel. You can check this as follows:

1. Open Excel and write this number 1234567890123456789 in a cell.
2. Press enter
3. You will see it shows this 1234567890123450000

Comment: I changed the format to obejct in the dataframe, but it still rounds

Comment: Makes sense. It is the way excel works